# javascript toggle click is not working in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a toggle click in addEventListener. but it is works only the first click and nothing change by more clicking. it shouold work invisible to visible and visible to invisible.

it is working now invisible to visible only. not working visible to invisible as return.

[image]

Code:

```js
document.getElementById("item-table").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("cancel-icon")) {
    tgt.closest("tr").remove();
  }

  if (tgt.classList.contains("visibility-icon")) {
    if (tgt.src == "icon/visible.png") {
      tgt.src = "icon/invisible.png";
      tgt.closest(".visibility-tr").style.color = "#ccc";
      tgt.closest(".visibility-tr").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.background = "#eee";
      tgt.closest(".visibility-tr").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.color = "#ccc";
    } else {
      tgt.src = "icon/visible.png";
      tgt.closest(".visibility-tr").style.color = "#000";
      tgt.closest(".visibility-tr").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.background = "#fff";
      tgt.closest(".visibility-tr").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.color = "#000";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="item-table">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Name: </strong></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="visibility-tr">
    <td><strong>Unit: </strong></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><img src="icon/invisible.png" class="visibility-icon" height="25px"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong>Price: </strong></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong>In Stock: </strong></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `tgt.src` contains the fully parsed and expanded URL, `https://yourdomain.com/icon/visible.png`, so the comparison always fails.

Use `tgt.getAttribute("src")` to get the attribute that hasn't been expanded.

```js
document.getElementById("item-table").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("cancel-icon")) {
    tgt.closest("tr").remove();
  }

  if (tgt.classList.contains("visibility-icon")) {
    if (tgt.getAttribute("src") == "icon/visible.png") {
      tgt.src = "icon/invisible.png";
      tgt.closest(".visibility-tr").style.color = "#ccc";
      tgt.closest(".visibility-tr").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.background = "#eee";
      tgt.closest(".visibility-tr").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.color = "#ccc";
    } else {
      tgt.src = "icon/visible.png";
      tgt.closest(".visibility-tr").style.color = "#000";
      tgt.closest(".visibility-tr").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.background = "#fff";
      tgt.closest(".visibility-tr").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.color = "#000";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="item-table">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Name: </strong></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="visibility-tr">
    <td><strong>Unit: </strong></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><img src="icon/invisible.png" class="visibility-icon" height="25px"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong>Price: </strong></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong>In Stock: </strong></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: wow! the simple changed is super answer! i got the perfect answer! thanks a lot sir!